# Removing Implication in the Conversion of WFF to Clausal Form

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, artificial-intelligence

I understand the conversion algorithm, my concern is regarding the first step of 'Removing Implication'.

Example: In the following figure when one removes implication, the negation comes before `∀z`.

[image]

However, in other example (given below) the negation when removing implies comes after `∀x` and before `∃z`.

```
∀x [Roman(x) ∧ know(x, Marcus)] → [hate(x, Caesar) ∨ (∀y ∃z hate(y, z) → thinkCrazy(x, y))]

∀x ~[Roman(x) ∧ know(x, Marcus)] ∨ [hate(x, Caesar)  ∨ (∀y ~(∃z hate(y, z)) ∨ thinkCrazy(x, y))]
```

I found a similar example [here](https://www.mil.ufl.edu/5840/exams/Old%20Exams/solpexa2_f09.pdf) where `~` is placed after `∀`.

I am confused about the placement of `~` while performing the first step during the conversion. What is the criteria of negating the implication when there exists either of the two quantifiers?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the order of operations by which you parse $\forall x~\phi\to \psi$

$$\color{crimson}(\forall x~\phi\color{crimson})~\to~\psi\iff \lnot\color{crimson}(\forall x~\phi\color{crimson})~\lor~\psi\\\forall x~~\color{crimson}(\phi\to \psi\color{crimson})\iff \forall x~~\color{crimson}(\lnot \phi\lor \psi\color{crimson})$$

The former is the usual convention, but it looks like your other source uses the later.

Unfortunately *different authors use different conventions*, so it can often be confusing if they don't clearly establish which operation has priority.

When it is ambiguous, use parenthesis.

Comment: And what if I have a combination of both quantifiers without parenthesis like: `∃x ∀z`, `∀x ∃z`, `∀x ∀z` or `∃x ∃z`. Is there any general rule for them?